# IllegalArgumentException from drawImage in Graphics2D on Windows

Tags: java, graphics

I'm getting following error on windows (but not on OSX):

```
Exception in thread "Engine" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Width (0) and height (0) cannot be <= 0
    at java.awt.image.DirectColorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.DrawImage.renderImageXform(Unknown Source)
    at sun.java2d.d3d.D3DDrawImage.renderImageXform(Unknown Source)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.DrawImage.transformImage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.DrawImage.scaleImage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.DrawImage.scaleImage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.java2d.pipe.ValidatePipe.scaleImage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.drawImage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.drawImage(Unknown Source)
    at simpleEngine.graphics.GameGraphics.drawGameObject(GameGraphics.java:27)
```

with the following code:

```
public void drawGameObject(GameObject obj, BufferedImage image) {
    graphics2d.rotate(obj.getRotation(), obj.getX() + obj.getWidth()/2, obj.getY() + obj.getHeight()/2);
    graphics2d.drawImage(image, (int) obj.getX(), (int) obj.getY(), (int) obj.getWidth(), (int) obj.getHeight(), null);
    graphics2d.rotate(-obj.getRotation(), obj.getX() + obj.getWidth()/2, obj.getY() + obj.getHeight()/2);
}
```

GameObject is an object to represent in a space. It has the fields position (double x and y), size (double width and height) and rotation (double in rads) and getters and setters for mentioned fields.

What I don't understand is where the zero height and width comes from. In this instance the obj has the width and height of 30, the image has the width and height of 535.

Any and all help will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
The reference to the Graphics2D object is supplied when the class is initiated. The class which this method is from is a wrapper around Graphics2D with methods that simplify work in my project. When I retrieve the Graphics2D I wrap it in this class and pass that along.
(Thanks to MadProgrammer to point out that missing bit of info!)

I've found that the problem is resolved if the rotation code is removed from drawGameObject. It won't cash, but no rotated sprites.

I've found that rotation was a NaN and was causing the problem. Still no idea why it didn't complain on OS X though..

Comment: Where does the reference  to Graphics2D come from?

Comment: I edited the question to answer your question since I thought more people could use that info to answer the question.

Comment: If you're using getGraphics from a Componet based on JComponent, then don't. To is not how painting is done. If the Graphics is coming from something like a BufferedStrategy, the it should be validated and changed on each paint cycle

Comment: I do retrieve Graphics2D every draw cycle from a BufferStrategy. The weird part is it works flawlessly on OS X but crashes on Windows 7.

Comment: Without a runnable example that demonstrates your problem, it's going to be impossible to diagnose your problem

Comment: All source is on Github at the following links:
https://github.com/MrLarssonJr/FlagHolder
https://github.com/MrLarssonJr/Game_Engine

And link to runnable jar
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0PbQ_ldw1ClNTVnaWdXMGpyVWM/edit?usp=sharing
(start with the flag local)

Answer (score 0):

I've found that rotation was a NaN and was causing the problem when rotating the graphics with it. Still no idea why it didn't complain on OS X though..

Answer (score 0):

if you realy use your statement like you wrote then the error is in the last line:

```
graphics2d.rotate(obj.getRotation(), obj.getX() + obj.getWidth()/2, obj.getY() + obj.getHeight()/2);
```

you have written `-obj.getRotation()`

Comment: I thank you for willingness to help! I appreciate it!

But I use the negative rotation to rotate the graphics back to it's normal position, and it works as expected.

I found that the problem was that the rotation was NaN. I wrote an answer about it but can first select it as the correct one in two hours.